# C# CloseMainWindow

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have a need to close another application that I wrote programmatically with C#.  I followed the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) and it worked with notepad.  But it doesn't work with the WinForms app that I wrote.

For example, when I open an instance of Notepad, then execute the following code:

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

if (procs.Length > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
    {
        Process p = procs[i];
        p.CloseMainWindow();
    }
}
```

Notepad will close.  However, when I use the same code, but I substitute "notepad" for the name of my application like this:

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyTestApp");

if (procs.Length > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
    {
        Process p = procs[i];
        p.CloseMainWindow();
    }
}
```

my application does not close.

Is there something that I have to do in the target app in order to respond to the CloseMainWindow() call from the other app?  I'd like to do a graceful shutdown, and would prefer not to use Process.Kill() if I can avoid it.

Comment: Have you debugged? Are any processes returned?

Comment: Yeah.  When I put a break point inside the for loop, p is set to the correct process (matched by Process ID), but the CloseMainWindow() call returns false.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: why dont you try Process.Kill() instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application's main window is not setup to terminate when the main window is closed. This would be the equivalent to right clicking the application on the task bar and selecting 'Close'.

Possibly try calling the following as it will stop awaiting an exit and additionally closes the process handle & properties:

```
p.Close();
```

Also please note, Process.CloseMainWindow closes a process that HAS as user interface by sending the close message to its main window. As you stated in a comment above, the call is returning false. This implies that your application does in fact not have a main window; thus you are returned with no action performed on your application.

UPDATE:
Can you try the code below to see if this works out for you.

```
// This will send a close message to the main window.
p.CloseMainWindow();

// This will free the associated resources. 
p.Close();
```

Comment: "It sounds like your application's main window is not setup to terminate when the main window is closed."  --How do I do this?

Comment: Please see my latest edit/update to see if this helps you out.